# Generics in TypeScript: How to infer the type of an instance from the class

Tags: class, generics, typescript, instance, typeof

A factory function creates the instances of classes:

```
class A {
    name: string
}
function factory<T>(Cl): T {
    return new Cl()
}
let a = factory<A>(A)
a.name // OK
```

I would like to avoid the repetition of `A` in: `factory<A>(A)`. The generics instance type should be able to be inferred from the class type, shouldn't be?

I tried this code:

```
function factory<T>(Cl: typeof T): T { // Error: Cannot find name 'T'
    return new Cl()
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the Typescript [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) :

> When creating factories in TypeScript using generics, it is necessary
>   to refer to class types by their constructor functions.

So you must do something like this:

```
function factory<T>(Cl: { new(): T; }): T {
    return new Cl();
}
```

In the code above, `Cl` must a type that at least has a constructor which return `T` generic type.

So the type inference will work:

```
let a = factory(A);
a.name;
```

You don't need to specify the type of `A` anyway because the compiler know it.